# MYSQL: detect multi-tabbing users

Tags: mysql

Say i have this table:

```
+----+------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| id | user | timestamp           | referrer                |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | foo  | 2012-08-26 14:05:55 | http://fubar.com/online |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 2  | foo  | 2012-08-26 14:05:59 | http://fubar.com/chat   |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 3  | bar  | 2012-08-27 07:06:07 | http://fubar.com/chat   |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 4  | max  | 2012-08-28 14:08:12 | http://fubar.com/chat   |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| 5  | max  | 2012-08-28 14:08:36 | http://fubar.com/online |
+----+------+---------------------+-------------------------+
```

i want to select all users who has both more than 1 referrer and timestamps are the same up to the minute precision

this would mean that during a span of 1 minute, they were viewing 2 pages of the same site and thus could imply that they are multi-tabbing. so in the table above, foo and max would fit the criteria.

i want to know how i can achieve this in mysql.

thank you.

Comment: If `referrer` is the value of an HTTP request's `Referer:` header, then one cannot draw the conclusion that a user was "*viewing 2 pages of the same site*": they might have been directed to a single page of the site from two different sources.  I would also suggest that one would need a much tighter bound than 1 minute to conclude that a user may be multi-tabbing: indeed, on many sites it would be quite normal for a user to move on from one page to the next (even if using only one tab) in a matter of seconds.

Comment: A better approach might be to look at the paths followed and determine whether there was more than one active path at any given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a self-join and use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) in the join cirteria:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user
FROM   my_table a JOIN my_table b ON
       a.user     =  b.user
   AND a.id       <  b.id
   AND a.referrer <> b.referrer
   AND ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.timestamp, b.timestamp)) <= 60
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f9d5e/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

How about something with the "having" clause?

```
SELECT user, COUNT(user) AS tabCount FROM whatever
 GROUP BY user
HAVING tabCount > 1;
```

Comment: no. that would mean adding a new column or whatever to the existing legacy database. i want an approach that deals with what is currently available as much as possible.

Comment: The only column I used is user, which you have in your table.  I should point out that "whatever" is the table name.  You didn't provide one in your example, so I just chose "whatever".